# No form validation on previous button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a multiple pages `form` where people can press `next` and `previous`. The form validates when trying to click `next` but it also validates when they click `previous`, which shouldn't be the case.

I've searched on Google and used some solutions provided by different websites such as `class="cancel"` or `formnovalidate="formnovalidate"` but nothing has worked for me so far.

These are my two buttons who are both in a form

```
<button data-role="prevbutton" class="btn btn-secondary pull-left">Previous</button>
<button data-role="nextbutton" class="btn btn-primary">Next</button>
```

There is no simple JS code that calls a function but more like this:

```
flow.isBelgianResidentChangeHandler = function(isBelgianResident) { 
if (isBelgianResident) { 
$('[data-role="nextbutton"]').attr('disabled', false); 
} else { 
$('[data-role="nextbutton"]').attr('disabled', true); 
} };
```

Comment: Please provide the relevant JS/JQuery code that validates your forms

Comment: Also please flag this jQuery Mobile if that is what it is

Comment: It's not jQuery mobile, it's web.

Comment: What is the function that's called when you click on the `nextbutton` element?

Comment: Forms don't validate themselves for the most part unless your using the HTML form attributes... so its def some javascript, please post the js code

Comment: I'm trying to find the code, it's a huge project that I didn't make myself.

Comment: Also if your using prev/next I'm guessing your using javascript asynchronously so your not reloading the page every time?

Comment: have you tried disableValidation="true"

Comment: @Greg So you're telling us you didn't even look at the code yet and already posted on SO to ask for help?

Comment: @JordanDavis Indeed, it does not reload

Comment: @VinayPandey Tried it now, but doesn't work

Comment: @JeffNoel I did, I checked all JS files, there's nothing that looks like a simple JS function when you click on a button. It's more like this: `flow.isBelgianResidentChangeHandler = function(isBelgianResident) {
    if (isBelgianResident) {
        $('[data-role="nextbutton"]').attr('disabled', false);
    } else {
        $('[data-role="nextbutton"]').attr('disabled', true);
    }
};`

Comment: Yea post all that in the main thread so we can see

Comment: @Greg there is definitely more to that code you posted above, since your using someone else code and functions, and clearly its not working, why don't you list the form(s) and form fields you need and I'll make you the functionality in pure JS.

Comment: The code you posted is related to disabling the Next button or not. It has no direct link with the issue you are  talking about.

Comment: @JeffNoel Yeah I know, I just can't seem to find it at all. I should ask my colleagues.

Comment: To be honest if it's async there really should be a `<form onsubmit="return false;">` or a `e.preventDefault` so the form isn't submitting, and or not even use a `<form>` tag but clearly there is a `<form>` tag

Comment: @Greg just list your forms, and form fields in bullets at the top and I'll make you a turn key solution you can copy in.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know without seeing your JavaScript code, but it could be because the default behavior of button elements in a form are to be submit buttons. So, whichever button you pressed, it would still submit your form. If this is the problem, then adding `type="button"` to your previous button will fix it.

```
<button data-role="prevbutton" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary pull-left">Previous</button>
```

Comment: could be a solution, to early to really tell without knowing his code like you said, so lets wait till he updates his code.